# Why do we clearly have $U=f^{-1}V$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following is Hartshorne Proposition II 6.8 and its proof.

> Prop 6.8: Let $X$ be a complete nonsingular curve over $k$, let $Y$ be any curve over $k$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism.  Then either (1) $f(X)=$ a point, or (2) $f(X)=Y$.  In case (2), $K(X)$ is a finite extension field of $K(Y)$, $f$ is a finite morphism, and $Y$ is also complete.

> Proof. Since $X$ is complete, $f(X)$ must be closed in $Y$, and proper over $\operatorname{Spec} k$. On the other hand, $f(X)$ is irreducible. Thus either (1)$f(X)=pt$, or (2)$f(X)=Y$, and in case (2), $Y$ is also complete.
> In case (2), $f$ is dominant, so it induces an inclusion $K(Y)\subseteq K(X)$ of function fields. Since both fields are finitely generated extension fields of transcendence degree 1 of $k$, $K(X)$ must be a finite algebraic extension of $K(Y)$. To show that $f$ is a finite morphism, let $V=\operatorname{Spec} B$ be any open affine subset of $Y$. Let $A$ be the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$. Then $A$ is a finite $B$-module, and $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is isomorphic to an open subset $U$ of $X$. Clearly $U=f^{-1}V$, so this shows that $f$ is a finite morphism.

My question: why do we clearly have $U=f^{-1}V$?

The following is a professor's answer.

> Apply the following conclusion.

1. For any Dedekind domain $A$, we have $A=\cap_\mathfrak pA_\mathfrak p$, where $\mathfrak p$ goes over the set of nonzero prime ideals of $A$.
2. We have a 1-1 correspondence between the set of nonzero primes ideals of of $A$ and the set of discrete valuations $v$ for the fraction field $K(A)$ of $A$ such that $A\subseteq R_v$, where $R_v$ is the discrete valuation ring of $v$. So $A=\cap_{v, v(A)\ge 0} R_v$.
3. A discrete valuation $u$ of $K(Y)$ lies in $f^{-1}(V)$ if and only if $u(B)\ge 0$, if and only if $u(A)\ge 0$.

What's the meaning of "a discrete valuation $u$ of $K(Y)$ lies in $f^{-1}(V)"$?